# How to sync values in a table column in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, synchronization, where-clause

I need to sync values in a table column in mysql trigger while having the same value in another column. Here is an example of my table:

id___MP____sweek

1____2_____1

2____2_____1

3____1_____2

4____1_____2

5____3_____3

6____3_____3

If a user changes, for example, MP in the first row (id=1) from 2 to 4, then the value of MP with the same sweek has to be changed (e.g., id=2, MP becomes also 4).

I wrote a BEFORE UPDATE tigger that does not work:

```
USE moodle;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_course_minpostUPD BEFORE UPDATE ON moodle.mdl_course_sections FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN

    IF NEW.MP <> OLD.MP THEN 
    BEGIN
        SET @A=NEW.MP;
        SET NEW.MP = @A
        WHERE OLD.sweek=NEW.sweek;
    END;
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From within a MySQL trigger you are not able to affect other rows on the same table.
You would want to say something like:

```
UPDATE my_table SET MP=NEW.MP WHERE sweek = NEW.sweek
```

But - sorry - no go.
There are hack around this -- and ugly ones, too.
If your table is MyISAM, you can wrap it up with a MERGE table, and act on the MERGE table instead (MySQL doesn't realize at that point you're actually hacking around it).

However, using MyISAM as a storage engine may not be a good thing -- today's focus is on InnoDB, a much more sophisticated engine.

Another trick is to try and use the FEDERATED engine. See relevant post by [Roland Bouman](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/mysql-hacks-preventing-deletion-of.html). Again, this is a dirty hack.

I would probably let the application do the thing within the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shlomi, for your helpful answer. It looks like I should use PHP to disable users' submissions of more than one entry rather than trying to sync them. Eugene